# Ruby dynamic binding variable as object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

Consider the following loop

```
{% for product in collections.settings[collection_setting].products %}

 {{ settings[collection_setting] }} - {{ product.title }}

{% endfor %}
```

Here **settings[collection_setting]** is equal to **green** but this does not work. If I have this static it works example

```
{% for product in collections.green.products %}

 {{ settings[collection_setting] }} - {{ product.title }}

{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone please explain why this happens and how to solve this.

**Answer**

Sorry for wasting your time. This [helps me to work](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle).

Working

```
{% for product in collections[settings[collection_setting]].products %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`collection_setting` seems to be a ruby variable. Hence to have the liquid template engine evaluate this, you'll need to have it in double braces (`{{collection_setting}}`).

Answer (score 0):

Where you have this:

```
{% for product in collections.settings[collection_setting].products %}
```

...are you sure you don't mean this?

```
{% for product in collections[collection_setting].products %}
```

Your non-working example has a `.settings` where your working example does not.